# Hibernate: @GeneratedValue doesn't work?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, annotations

I have entity like below, but can't undestand why when i add new record, generated id is 50, 51, 52... if `select nextval('seq_text');` return 1523, 1524... Database: PostgreSQL.
Something wrong ?

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_text", sequenceName = "seq_text")
public class Text {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_text")
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of your seq_text sequence? Do you have cache parameter specified?

Comment: Cache checked on db -> 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the declaration that you use is using HiLo generator.
Here is a discussion and workaround:
http://community.jboss.org/thread/107819?tstart=0

Proposed workaround is

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_text", sequenceName = "seq_text", allocationSize=1)
```